# Is a move constructor generated when a class has a user-provided copy constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, move-semantics, move-constructor

C++ standard says (12.8/9):

> If the definition of a class `X` does not explicitly declare a move constructor, one will be implicitly declared as defaulted if and only if
>
> - `X` does not have a user-declared copy constructor,
> - `X` does not have a user-declared copy assignment operator,
> - `X` does not have a user-declared move assignment operator, and
> - `X` does not have a user-declared destructor.

But the following code (compiled with [*clang++ 3.8.0* and *g++ 6.3.0*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/05a50b2176a79daf)) gives an empty output:

```
#include <iostream>


struct Foo
{
    
    Foo() = default;
    
    Foo(const Foo&)
    {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    
};


int main()
{
    Foo foo{Foo{}};
    
    (void)foo;
}
```

Is it a problem in *clang++* and *g++*?

**Upd.** As [**@Piotr Skotnicki**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3953764/piotr-skotnicki) noted in comments a [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) takes place here. The command-line key `-fno-elide-constructors` [disables it for constructors in *clang++* and *g++*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e71fc03f55d67b42).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12953127/3953764

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki But no optimization flags are enabled here.

Comment: Neither is `-fno-elide-constructors`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Yes, [it works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e71fc03f55d67b42). Thank you. Could you post your comment as an answer so I could accept it?

Comment: Note that in C++17, this isn't even move elision. There's imply no move - it's just exactly equivalent to `Foo foo{}`.

Comment: @Barry Do you mean "guaranteed copy elision"?